# need to grab entire first element (array) in a multi-dimentional list of arrays python3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Apologies if this has already been asked, but I searched quite a bit and couldn't find quite the right solution. I'm new to python, but I'll try to be as clear as possible. In short, I have a list of arrays in the following format resulting from a joining a multiprocessing pool:

```
array = [[[1,2,3], 5, 47, 2515],..... [[4,5,6], 3, 35, 2096]]]
```

and I want to get all values from the first array element to form a new array in the following form:

```
print(new_array)
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

In my code, I was trying to get the first value through this function:

```
new_array = array[0][0]
```

but this only returns the first value as such:

```
print(new_array)
[1,2,3]
```

I also tried np.take after converting the array into a np array:

```
array = np.array(array)

new_array = np.take(results,0)

print(new_array)

[1,2,3]
```

I have tried a number of np functions (concatenate, take, etc.) to try and iterate this over the list, but get back the following error (presumably because the size of the array changes):

```
ValueError: autodetected range of [[], [1445.0, 1445.0, -248.0, 638.0, -108.0, 649.0]] is not finite
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just using the example list, `np.array(array)` produces a (2,4) shape object dtype array.  and indexing with `[:,0]` returns these initial lists, which can be joined with `hstack`.  But you subsequent error suggests that the sublists aren't always the same length and mix.

Comment: Correct, they're not. I'm parsing my data by chromosome for multi-threading, so I'm not guaranteed to have the same number of positive hits (results in the array list I wanted to move to the new array) for each chromosome leading to the variation in length and mix.

Comment: With that variable size, the list approach is better than a numpy one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it without numpy using reduce:

```
from functools import reduce
l = [[[1,2,3], 5, 47, 2515], [[4,5,6], 3, 35, 2096]]
res = reduce(lambda a, b: [*a, *b], [x[0] for x in l])
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Maybe it is worth mentioning that `[*a, *b]` is a way to concatenate lists in python, for example:

```
[*[1, 2, 3], *[4, 5, 6]]  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use itertools' chain() function to flatten an extraction of the first subArray in each element of the list:

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(chain(*[sub[0] for sub in array]))
```